# Spring boot fails on PUT of an entity with many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

Recently I have upgraded SpringBoot version from 1.4.0.RELEASE to 1.4.3.RELEASE. Surprisingly this caused that one of my entities cannot be persisted using Spring data rest API using PUT method which results in:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of ...Authority was altered from 2 to 3

Authority entity:

```
@Entity
public class Authority {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private AccessLevel authority;
private Integer level;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public AccessLevel getAuthority() {
    return authority;
}

public void setAuthority(AccessLevel authority) {
    this.authority = authority;
}

public Integer getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public void setLevel(Integer level) {
    this.level = level;
}

}
```

Member entity (owns Authorities):

```
@Entity
public class Member extends Auditable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@NotNull
private String firstName;
@NotNull
private String lastName;
@NotNull
@Email
private String email;
@Column(unique = true)
@NotNull
private String login;
@NotNull
private String password;
private boolean enabled;
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Authority> authorities;

public Member() {
    enabled = true;
    authorities = new HashSet<>();
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getLogin() {
    return login;
}

public void setLogin(String login) {
    this.login = login;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public Set<Authority> getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

}
```

Authority repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)
public interface AuthorityRepository extends CrudRepository<Authority, Long> {

}
```

Member repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface MemberRepository extends CrudRepository<Member, Long> {

@RestResource(exported = false)
Member findOneByLogin(String login);

}
```

From UI there is executed put method on https://localhost:8443/api/members/8 endpoint with content:

```
{
"created": "2016-10-25T12:44:09.988",
"modified": "2016-10-25T12:44:15.028",
"firstName": "***",
"lastName": "***",
"email": "***",
"login": "***",
"password": "***",
"enabled": true,
"authorities": [{
        "id": 3,
        "authority": "ANALYST",
        "level": 3
    }, {
        "id": 5,
        "authority": "CONTRACTOR",
        "level": 5
    }, {
        "id": 4,
        "authority": "EXPERT",
        "level": 4
    }],
"_links": {
    "self": {
        "href": "https://localhost:8443/api/members/8"
    },
    "member": {
        "href": "https://localhost:8443/api/members/8"
    },
    "modifier": {
        "href": "https://localhost:8443/api/members/8/modifier"
    },
    "creator": {
        "href": "https://localhost:8443/api/members/8/creator"
    }
}
}
```

If I remove authorities attribute before executing request it works but then I cannot manage authorities.

Reverting back to SpringBoot 1.4.0.RELEASE makes this issue dissapear. Have you encoutered such problem or have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: What does the original GET from api/members/8 look like? And what are you trying to change?

Comment: GET works for both 1.4.0 and 1.4.3 properly. Request to api/members/8 returns proper json. I'm trying to execute POST/PUT requests which results in following exception: org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of ...Authority was altered from 2 to 3